# resignFirstResponder for all textfields

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

I'm working on an iphone app with multiple `textfields` on a `viewcontroller`. I'm a bit confused with `resignfirstresponder` and setting `textfield delegates`.I've been able to resign text fields when I set the delegate for one then call `resignfirstresponder` for that particular textfield. 
I have a `view controller` with about 7 text fields and don't want to call each individually. Does anyone have any example code that will close all of the `textfields` on a `view controller`? Also how do you set the delegate for all textfields?

Thanks!

Comment: For multiple TextFields use this Approach : http://stackoverflow.com/a/13991703/1603072

Answer (score 215):

try using this

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

This will hide keyboard if its presented due to a subview of your self.view

Comment: Thanks and do i need to do a sometextfield.delegate=self in viewdidload()?

Comment: not necessary to do that. in case you need you may also do the same in  Interfacebuilder. For a large number of textfields, do for one , and then copy and paste it(a quicker way).

Comment: It's funny that although it's stated in the document `This method looks at the current view and its subview hierarchy for the text field that is currently the first responder`, it works for text views as well.

Comment: For swift try this
self.view!.endEditing(true)

Comment: @BalajiGupta : Kindly show this appreciation in Inx's Tuesday meeting.