# How to dismiss keyboard iOS programmatically when pressing return

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextfield

I created a `UITextField` programmatically making the `UITextField` a property of the viewController. I need to dismiss the keyboard with the return and the touch on the screen. I was able to get the screen touch to dismiss, but pressing return is not working.

I've seen how to do it with storyboards and by allocating and initializing the `UITextField` object directly without creating it as a property. Possible to do?

#### .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (strong, atomic) UITextField *username;

@end
```

#### .m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    self.username = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 25, 80, 20)];
    self.username.placeholder = @"Enter your username";
    self.username.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.username.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    if (self.username.placeholder != nil) {
        self.username.clearsOnBeginEditing = NO;
    }
    _username.delegate = self; 
    
    [self.view addSubview:self.username];
    [_username resignFirstResponder];
    
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    NSLog(@"touchesBegan:withEvent:");
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

@end
```

Comment: [Magical single line code !!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13991703/1603072)

Answer (score 289, accepted):

The simple way is to connect the delegate of `UITextField` to self (`self.mytestField.delegate = self`) and dismiss the keyboard in the method `textFieldShouldReturn` using `[textField resignFirstResponder];`

Another way to dismiss the keyboard is the following:

**Objective-C**

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

**Swift:**

```
self.view.endEditing(true)
```

Put `[self.view endEditing:YES];` where you would like to dismiss the keyboard (Button event, Touch event, etc.).

Comment: when I connect the delegate, though, I get warnings and/or errors. I've seen your way before, but for some reason can't get it to work.Would these methods go in viewDidLoad?

Comment: If you were getting error's when you tried to set the textField delegate to self, then you've probably not added UITextFieldDelegate to the class definition. Specifically ... class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate { ...

Answer (score 32):

simply use this in swift to dismiss keyboard:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction("resignFirstResponder", to:nil, from:nil, forEvent:nil)
```

**Swift 3**

```
UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resign‌​FirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
```

Comment: SWIFT 3 `UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)`

Answer (score 31):

Add a delegate method of `UITextField` like this:

```
@interface MyController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

And set your `textField.delegate = self;` then also add two delegate methods of `UITextField`

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{   
    return YES;
}

// It is important for you to hide the keyboard
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: We should add, that the above only works, if your controller implements the UITextFieldDelegate like so:

`@interface MyController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>`

Comment: @iPatel I put those 2 methods in, and also added self.username.delegate = self and [self.username resignFirstResponder] in viewDidLoad. This works for both scenarios I needed. Is that normal or am I using too much code?

Answer (score 26):

//Hide keyBoard by touching background in view

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [[self view] endEditing:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 23):

**SWIFT 4:**

```
self.view.endEditing(true)
```

or

Set text field's delegate to current viewcontroller and then:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    return true

}
```

**Objective-C:**

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

or

Set text field's delegate to current viewcontroller and then:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

In the App Delegate, you can write

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.window endEditing:YES];
}
```

use this way, you can don`t write too much code.

Answer (score 7):

Try to get an idea about what a first responder is in iOS view hierarchy. When your textfield becomes active(or first responder) when you touch inside it (or pass it the messasge `becomeFirstResponder` programmatically), it presents the keyboard. So to remove your textfield from being the first responder, you should pass the message `resignFirstResponder` to it there.

```
[textField resignFirstResponder];
```

And to hide the keyboard on its return button, you should implement its delegate method `textFieldShouldReturn:` and pass the `resignFirstResponder` message.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's what I use in my code. It works like a charm!

In yourviewcontroller.h add:

`@property (nonatomic) UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer;`

Now in the .m file, add this to your ViewDidLoad function:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Keyboard stuff
    tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    tapRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
}
```

Also, add this function in the .m file:

```
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Comment: just remember the action:@selector should call the same method name where you do endEditing:YES, in this case "handleSingleTap:"

Answer (score 5):

For a group of `UITextView`s inside a `ViewController`:

**Swift 3.0**

```
for view in view.subviews {
    if view is UITextField {
        view.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

**Objective-C**

```
// hide keyboard before dismiss
for (UIView *view in [self.view subviews]) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        // no need to cast
        [view resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To dismiss a keyboard after the keyboard has popped up, there are **2 cases**,

1. when the UITextField is **inside a UIScrollView**
2. when the UITextField is **outside a UIScrollView**

2.when the UITextField is outside a UIScrollView
override the method in your UIViewController subclass

you must also **add delegate for all UITextView**

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

1. In a **scroll view, Tapping outside will not fire any event**, so in that case **use a Tap Gesture Recognizer**,
   Drag and drop a **UITapGesture** for the scroll view and **create an IBAction for it**.

to create a IBAction, press ctrl+ click the UITapGesture and drag it to the .h file of viewcontroller.

Here I have named tappedEvent as my action name

```
- (IBAction)tappedEvent:(id)sender {
      [self.view endEditing:YES];  }
```

the abouve given Information was derived from the following link, please refer for more information or contact me if you dont understand the abouve data.

http://samwize.com/2014/03/27/dismiss-keyboard-when-tap-outside-a-uitextfield-slash-uitextview/

Comment: Thanks. Your answer helped me..!

Answer (score 3):

Since the tags only say iOS i will post the answer for Swift 1.2 and iOs 8.4, add these in your view controller swift class:

```
// MARK: - Close keyboard when touching somewhere else
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    self.view.endEditing(true)

}

// MARK: - Close keyboard when return pressed
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {

    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    return true
}
// MARK: -
```

Also do not forget to add UITextFieldDelegate in the class declaration and set your text fields delegate to self (the view).

Answer (score 3):

**IN Swift 3**

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
```

**OR**

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if textField == yourtextfieldName
        {
            self.resignFirstResponder()
            self.view.endEditing(true)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

First you need to add textfield delegete in .h file. if not declare 
`(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField` this method not called.so first add delegate and write keyboard hide code into that method.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

try this one..

Answer (score 2):

So here's what I did to make it dismiss after touching the background or return. I had to add the delegate = self in viewDidLoad and then also the delegate methods later in the .m files.

```
.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>


@property (strong, atomic) UITextField *username;

@end

.m
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    self.username = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 25, 80, 20)];
    self.username.placeholder = @"Enter your username";
    self.username.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.username.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    if (self.username.placeholder != nil) {
        self.username.clearsOnBeginEditing = NO;
    }
    self.username.delegate = self;
    [self.username resignFirstResponder];
    [self.view addSubview:self.username];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    return YES;
}



- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use this in Objective-C to dismiss keyboard:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow endEditing:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Delegate : UITextFieldDelegate

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

and then add this delegate method

// This should work perfectly

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
[self.view.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIView* obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        [obj resignFirstResponder];
    }
}];
}
```

when you using more then one textfield in screen 
With this method you doesn't need to mention textfield every time like

```
[textField1 resignFirstResponder];
[textField2 resignFirstResponder];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 2 :**

this is what is did to do every thing !

close keyboard with `Done` button or `Touch outSide` ,`Next` for go to next input.

First Change TextFiled `Return Key` To `Next` in StoryBoard.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  txtBillIdentifier.delegate = self
  txtBillIdentifier.tag = 1
  txtPayIdentifier.delegate  = self
  txtPayIdentifier.tag  = 2

  let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "onTouchGesture")
  self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
   if(textField.returnKeyType == UIReturnKeyType.Default) {
       if let next = textField.superview?.viewWithTag(textField.tag+1) as? UITextField {
           next.becomeFirstResponder()
           return false
       }
   }
   textField.resignFirstResponder()
   return false
}

func onTouchGesture(){
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know current view controller or textview you can use the Responder Chain:

```
UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIView.endEditing(_:)), to:nil, from:nil, for:nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

**for swift 3-4** i fixed like

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

just copy paste anywhere on the class. This solution just work if you want all UItextfield work as same, or if you have just one!