# Hide keyboard by pressing button

Tags: ios, swift

how can I hide the keyboard by simply pressing a button? For example when you want to type something into a textField and the keyboard should disappear after pressing a button which calls an action.

Comment: try calling `endEditing:` on your textfield when you want to hide the keyboard

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dismiss keyboard iOS programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755410/how-to-dismiss-keyboard-ios-programmatically)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[self.view endEditing:YES]
```

Paste it in action handler of your controller.
Or for Swift:

```
self.view.endEditing(true)
```

Comment: in the action of my button?

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: You can as well get you text field and resignFirstResponder to achieve the same result. NP.

Answer (score 1):

For **objective c** :

```
[_nameOfYourTextField resignFirstResponder];
```

If you have multiple textViews in the view then

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

For **swift**:

```
nameOfYourTextField.resignFirstResponder()
```

If you have multiple textViews in the view then

```
self.view.endEditing(true)
```

Put these statements in your action method.