# Hide the IOS Keyboard

Tags: ios, uitextfield, ios-keyboard-extension

I have an `Text Field` in my layout, which gets filled out, and afterwards when clicking on the `UIButton` in the layout, I want to hide the virtual keyboard.

I assume this can be done easily?

Comment: yourTextBox.resignFirstResponder()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dismiss keyboard iOS programmatically when pressing return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755410/how-to-dismiss-keyboard-ios-programmatically-when-pressing-return)

Comment: _where can I find an example of it?_ - literally in the first link that appears on Google after typing `iOS hide keyboard`

Comment: @mag_zbc Im using a UIButton for dismissing the keyboard not the return key.

Comment: Dismissing keyboard works the same way, wherever you want to call it from

Comment: Make an outlet of your textField and add an action for the button for event touchupinside. See the apple docs how to create outlets and add actions. When the button is pressed the action method will be triggered, call self.textField.resignFirstResponder() or self.view.endEditing(true)

Answer (score 4):

You can put below line in button click action.

```
self.view.endEditing(true)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
extension UIViewController {
func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer =
        UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}
@objc func dismissKeyboard() {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

}

Use this Extension.

You can hide the Keyboard by tapping anywhere on the screen or just call dissmissKeyboard() to hide it.

Answer (score -2):

text box means UITextView?
if it is UITextView then resignFirstResponder() is not allowed

you have to hide keyboards by clicking on background view